# Rails form errors - validation

Tags: ruby-on-rails, validation, forms, error-handling

I'd like to be able to highlight fields that don't pass validation.  I'm using simple_form, and the error messages it displays just don't look good to me.  I'm listing the errors above the form & I'd like to highlight (change the color of) the fields that contain invalid values.  Is there an easy way of doing this?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

yes it's very easy, you will likely find that the field with errors will have a class of ".field_with_errors" or something similar applied to it

just style all inputs that fall within that class to have 2px solid red border

i.e.

```
// style.sass
.field_with_errors
  input
    border: 2px solid red
```

Comment: This set me on the right track -- ultimately, I also had to add field_with_error_fix.rb to  config/initializers.  The file contains the following code: ActionView::Base.field_error_proc = Proc.new { |html_tag, instance|
"<span class=\"fieldWithErrors\">#{html_tag}</span>" }

Answer (score 0):

You could also take a look at [client-side-validations](http://railscasts.com/episodes/263-client-side-validations). You can style and display errors inline, and it supports simple_form.